# How to return all stored fileds from Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to return all fields from a solr index. setting "fl" to a "*"
this should return all [stored fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-Thefl_FieldList_Parameter)

I have also tried to specify a field that are not returned, but then I get an empty result list.

From the schema.xml file.

This is returned:

```
<field name="IlexId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

But not this

```
<field name="AnnotatedTargetTranslationGramLemmaId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I am using the solr web admin UI to execute the query's.

Comment: Was the field set as `stored` when you indexed? Has the field definition been changed since any content was indexed? Are you changing anything else than the `fl`? Do you get any hits at all (what does the numDocs value say)?